# how to convert the Json to table in python

Tags: python

```
try:
    # For Python 3.0 and later
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    # Fall back to Python 2's urllib2
    from urllib2 import urlopen

import certifi
import json

def get_jsonparsed_data(url):
  
    response = urlopen(url, cafile=certifi.where())
    data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(data)

url = ("https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/ratios/AAPL?apikey=92a1dad5aef4eb31276c19417c31dfeb")
print(get_jsonparsed_data(URL))
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = (
    "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/ratios/AAPL?"
    "apikey=92a1dad5aef4eb31276c19417c31dfeb"
)
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

prints:

```
symbol  date    period  currentRatio    quickRatio  cashRatio   daysOfSalesOutstanding  daysOfInventoryOutstanding  operatingCycle  daysOfPayablesOutstanding   ... priceToSalesRatio   priceEarningsRatio  priceToFreeCashFlowsRatio   priceToOperatingCashFlowsRatio  priceCashFlowRatio  priceEarningsToGrowthRatio  priceSalesRatio dividendYield   enterpriseValueMultiple priceFairValue
0   AAPL    2021-09-25  FY  1.074553    0.909660    0.278449    51.390969   11.276593   62.667561   93.851071   ... 6.786117    26.219656   26.706799   23.861253   23.861253   0.367742    6.786117    0.005828    20.889553   39.348186
1   AAPL    2020-09-26  FY  1.363604    1.218195    0.360710    49.787534   8.741883    58.529418   91.048190   ... 7.272322    34.773150   27.211359   24.746031   24.746031   3.277438    7.272322    0.007053    25.558891   30.553901
2   AAPL    2019-09-28  FY  1.540126    1.384447    0.462022    64.258765   9.263639    73.522404   104.314077  ... 4.420394    20.813515   19.527159   16.573786   16.573786   -62.492578  4.420394    0.012277    14.772472   12.709658
3   AAPL    2018-09-29  FY  1.123843    0.986566    0.221733    67.332499   8.817631    76.150130   124.570214  ... 3.959898    17.666917   16.402259   13.582267   13.582267   0.597709    3.959898    0.013038    13.099961   9.815760
4   AAPL    2017-09-30  FY  1.276063    1.089670    0.201252    56.800671   12.563631   69.364302   126.927606  ... 3.794457    17.989671   17.121402   13.676823   13.676823   1.632758    3.794457    0.014680    12.605749   6.488908
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas
print(pandas.DataFrame(data))
```

I guess maybe what you are trying to do...